# Add a space after "Answer:" when sharing an answer

Tags: bug, status-completed

The generated title when sharing an answer to Twitter looks like this:

[image]

There should be a space after "Answer:" word, it looks much better:

[image]

Comment: Free-hand everything? I am overjoyed!

Comment: I think this should not be tagged as bug, this should be tagged as feature-request.

Comment: @IamtheMostStupidPerson The current practice of not having the space is wrong as most grammar guides you'll find will tell you to add a single space after the colon as long as you're not dealing with timestamps or (I believe) biblical references. So no, it should not be a [tag:feature-request].

Comment: Twitter is not the place for grammar.

Comment: @canon: It absolutely is. The 140 were often enough a flimsy excuse at best but with the 280 there is hardly any reason ever.

Comment: And please insert the FULL title of the question, because now [all question titles have been trimmed to 150 characters max](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/707395/questions-with-title-length-greater-than-150), and Twitter accepts 280 chars.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was a bug in localization where the space was correct but was being stripped. It also just in general wasn't correct for other languages but will be after the next build.

We have build warnings for space-at-the-end strings for exactly this reason (and warnings fail our builds). It works in our C#/Razor code, but obviously isn't happening in JavaScript...we'll take a look at that next.

Comment: Thanks. I will now share all my answers as a sign of respect to your fast response.